# Forge viewer slows down when added SVG on it

Tags: autodesk-forge, viewer

I am using Autodesk Forge's Markups core extension to draw some shapes on a forge viewer, which is rendering 2D sheet(rvt). Once I draw a shape I save its SVG in my DB to redraw it later. To redraw the shape I use markupExtension.loadMarkups(svgData, LayerName).

Somehow my forge viewer's performance slows when I redraw some shapes on the sheet. The zooming and selection of elements slows down.

Can someone please help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Using `markupExt.loadMarkups()` is the correct way to recreate the `<svg>` element with all your markups. It should provide the exact same performance as the markups you created earlier by hand.

Make sure that you're not accidentally calling the function multiple times, creating many copies of the same SVF markup. And if you're still having issues with the performance, please share your code here so we can have a look.

Comment: Alternatively, send us your code sample to forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am adding one layer for each markup when I load them on viewer, and while unloading the markup i am  unloading that particular layer. So at the end if I unload all the layers still the viewer performance is slow. Can you guess why it is happening?

Comment: It's hard to guess without seeing the code. If you could send us your implementation of loading/unloading markups (or a link to a working demo page) to the email address mentioned above, we'd be happy to take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You have more than one SVG element tag in your markup which is slowing your viewer down. Try to move all the markup elements in one svg.

Or

Are you trying to invalidate the viewer, if so then don't do it because your webGL canvas will be redrawn again and again

I was doing the same thing then I remove the line

NOP_VIEWER.impl.invalidate(true);